# Body extends to fit screen only in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm having problems trying to stop chrome from making the body fit the screen on here http://www.lgbtgamers.com/sessions . In Firefox it does not and it looks like the footer extends, in chrome it just leaves a white gap.

The CSS for this part:

```
*{ 
    margin: 0;  
    padding: 0; 
    vertical-align: baseline; 
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
    -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
    -o-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
}

html{ 
    font: 13px/1.4 Helvetica,arial,freesans,clean,sans-serif,"Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol"; 
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
    color: #4F565A; 
    background: #151515; 
}

body{ 
    background: #E5E5E5; 
}
```

Comment: What width do you want the body to be? Whatever width (x) this is, use body {x%;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be missing DOCTYPE declaration.

Just add the following at the very top of your html (even before the `<html>` element, on a line of its own, it must be the very FIRST LINE of the document):

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

This prevents Chrome going into quirks mode emulating odd behaviours of old browsers.